# 3 layouts e uma activity

Tags: android

Tenho uma actyvity_main, contendo 3 radiobuttons (cada um corresponde a um layout), e um botão. Após o usuário selecionar a opção, ele clica no botão, que faz uma chamada para outra activity, onde nela, preciso fazer com venha com o layout selecionado.

```html
public void onClick(View view) {
        int checkeRadioButtonId = escolhaRadio.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        switch (checkeRadioButtonId) {
            case R.id.rdb1:
                Intent opcao8 = new Intent(this, Activity_Jogo.class);
                setContentView(R.layout.layout_8);
                startActivity(opcao8);
                break;
            case R.id.rdb2:
                Intent opcao10 = new Intent(this, Activity_Jogo.class);
                setContentView(R.layout.layout_10);
                startActivity(opcao10);
                break;
            case R.id.rdb3:
                Intent opcao12 = new Intent(this, Activity_Jogo.class);
                setContentView(R.layout.layout_12);
                startActivity(opcao12);
        }
    }
```

Dessa maneira que estou fazendo, ele chama o layout e, após aparecer ele instantaneamente chama a activity, ficando somente a activity com seu layout padrão.

Comment: Tem de explicar melhor o que pretende. Uma coisa é certa o `setContentView()` só deve ser chamado uma vez em cada activity e deve sê-lo no método `onCreate()`.

Comment: Tem como eu chamar só uma activity, passando qual layout ela deve exibir?

Comment: Tem mas torna-se complicado gerir cada uma das Views que compõem cada um dos layouts passados. A melhor solução é usar fragments ou Activities diferentes.

Answer (score 1):

A forma mais simples seria passar o **resource** do `layout` por `Extras`, e recuperar na próxima `Activity`:

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    int checkeRadioButtonId = escolhaRadio.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    Intent i = new Intent(this, Activity_Jogo.class);

    switch (checkeRadioButtonId) {
        case R.id.rdb1:
            opcao10.putExtra("opcao", R.layout.layout_8);
            break;
        case R.id.rdb2:
            opcao10.putExtra("opcao", R.layout.layout_10);
            break;
        case R.id.rdb3:
            opcao10.putExtra("opcao", R.layout.layout_12);
            break;
    }

    startActivity(i);
}
```

No método `onCreate` da sua `Activity_Jogo` você recuperaria esse valor e usaria como `contentView`:

```
@Override
protected onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    int layout = getIntent().getIntExtra("opcao", 0);

    // Se ninguem passou um layout como parametro,
    // voce pode usar um padrao ou fechar a Activity
    if(layout == 0) {
        finish();
    }

    setContentView(layout);

    // Restante do seu processamento...
}
```

Comment: É uma possibilidade mas depois torna-se complicado gerir cada uma das *Views* que compõem cada um dos layouts passados. A melhor solução é usar fragments ou Activities diferentes.

Comment: @ramaral, sim, com certeza, não tinha pensado por esse lado. Minha solução só é ótima se os layouts possuem os mesmo elementos, mas com uma arrumação diferente.